# Returning a reference from a pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, c++11, reference, singleton

I have this class in `singleton.h`:

```
class SingletonSample {
public:
     static SingletonSample& Instance();
     int DoSomething() const;
private:
     SingletonSample();
     ~SingletonSample();
     SingletonSample(const SingletonSample&) = delete;
     SingletonSample& operator=(const SingletonSample&) = delete;
     static SingletonSample* _instance;
}
```

And I have this implementation in `singleton.cpp`:

```
SingletonSample::SingletonSample() {}
SingletonSample::~SingletonSample() {}
SingletonSample& SingletonSample::Instance() {
    if(!_instance) _instance = new SingletonSample();
    return _instance;
}
int SingletonSample::DoSomething() const {
    return 20;
}
```

I have a compiler error when trying to `return _instance`.

I want to return a `SingletonSample&`, but my `_instance` is a pointer `SingletonSample*`.

I'm a beginner in C++ but as far as I understand, a reference to something is just the address to that something, while a pointer to something is just a pointer to that address.

I would like to return that address being pointed by the pointer, as a reference `SingletonSample&`.

However, I cannot manage to achieve that. How can I do this?

Comment: even if you already got an answer, you might consider to post the compiler error.

Comment: Note that "reference" in Java has a different meaning than "reference" in C++.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A reference is not an address of an object. It is just an *alias* for one. You simply have to de-reference the pointer:

```
return *_instance;
```

This lets the reference refer to the object pointed at by `_instance`.

Note that the implementation can be greatly simplified:

```
SingletonSample& SingletonSample::Instance() {
  static SingletonSample instance;
  return instance;
}
```

Also note that singletons are [generally considered a bad idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/137975/what-is-so-bad-about-singletons).

Comment: Are you creating a new static member inside the `Instance` method? I didn't know that was possible!

Comment: @MatiCicero Yes, it is, and it is even thread-safe since C++11 (the creation if the instance, that is.)